# ¿how render collection or embed form in twig?

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, render

I would like you to please help me with the following problem.

I want to render an embedded form , but failed to do, they would be so kind as to tell me how to do it ?.
I appreciate your help.

> The problem: when I save the data, these are inserted into the database , but the Product table in the category_id field , NULL is inserted.

**CategoryType**

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')            
        ->add('products', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => new ProductType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
    ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'DeteccionBundle\Entity\Category'
    ));
}


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'category';
}
}
```

**ProductType**

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('price')
        //->add('category')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'DeteccionBundle\Entity\Product'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'product';
}
}
```

and this is my template twig:

```
{% block body -%}



{{ form_start(form) }}
    {# {{ form(form) }} #}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}


<a href="#" id="add-another-email">Añadir otro producto</a>
</ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script>
// keep track of how many email fields have been rendered
var emailCount = '{{ form.products|length }}';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var productList = jQuery('#category_products');

        // grab the prototype template
        var newWidget = productList.attr('data-prototype');
        // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
        // with a number that's unique to your products
        // end name attribute looks like name="contact[products][2]"
        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, emailCount);
        emailCount++;

        // create a new list element and add it to the list
        var newLi = jQuery('<li></li>').html(newWidget);
        newLi.appendTo(productList);
    });
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please note that `OptionsResolverInterface` has been deprecated since version 2.6. You should use `OptionsResolver` instead. Also, have you read the cookbook article about form collections? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: yes, realize and changes , but still does not work!

Comment: What errors you have got exactly?

Comment: when I save the data, these are inserted into the database , but the Product table in the category_id field , NULL is inserted.